# Ionic 3 Firebase & Code Push Plugin Replacement

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, capacitor

I have an Ionic 3 app that currently leverages an aging Firebase push notification Cordova plugin, and an aging Code Push (Microsoft app center) Cordova plugin.  For a new Ionic 5 app, I'm wondering what the most preferred Push Notification and Code Push solutions might be.  Secondarily, I'm wondering if I could use them with my Ionic 3 (cordova) app.  Upgrading to Ionic 5 is likely not possible for me, unfortunately.

**Push Notifications:** Would the best current option be the (free?) capacitor Push Notification plugin?

**Code Push:** Would the best current option be the (not free) Ionic App Flow integration?

Comment: With capacitor Push Notification plugin you will get raw device token, and you will have to manage all the logic to send the push from your back end. I really like OneSignal, it is free and easy to install. It allows you to send push with advanced options (tags, groups, session durations...) and provides analytics

Comment: Thanks for that insight.  We do have an aging Firebase plugin already, so handling the raw device token and the back-end push is OK with us.  We just need a plugin that is maintained as new OS's and Firebase changes happen.

Comment: With Firebase all device tokens have the same format. To send a push, you "just" need to make an API call to an FCM endpoint with the token and the push data. While with capacitor push notification, you won't have an unified token format. iOS tokens are different than Android tokens. To send a push, you will have to check what's the user platform, and then send the push via FCM for Android, or via the APNs for iOS

Comment: I agree.  We have this working today.  My concern is the old plugin we have in place today in our app.  I want to know what the most supported Firebase plugin option would be for a brand new Ionic/Cordova/Capacitor app.